# Happy, Hungry, Energy states

Tags: java, loops

I'm designing a simple tamagotchi with a Jpanel interface using Eclipse. Im trying to decide what would be best method to use when writing code for happy, hungry, energy states using loops, These are my two classes, I'm using abstract Animal class, and MyPet which extends an Animal class:

Animal Class:

```
package GroupAnimal;

import java.util.*;


public abstract class Animal
{
    protected int hungry;
    protected int happy;
    protected int energy;
    protected int toilet;
    protected int love;
    protected int health;
    protected int limbs;
    protected String name;
    protected String dob;
    protected double weight;
    protected double height;


    public int getHungry()
    {
        return hungry;
    }

    public int getHappy()
    {
        return happy;
    }

    public int getEnergy()
    {
        return energy;
    }

    public int gettoilet()
    {
        return toilet;
    }

    public int getLove()
    {
        return love;
    }

    public int getLimbs()
    {
        return limbs;
    }

    public int getHealth()
    {
        return health;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDob()
    {
        return dob;
    }

    public double getWeight()
    {
        return weight;
    }

    public double getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }

    protected void setName(String newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }

    protected void setHeight(double newHeight)
    {
        height = newHeight;
    }

    protected void setWeight(double newWeight)
    {
        weight = newWeight;
    }

    protected void setLimbs (int newLimbs)
    {
        limbs = newLimbs;
    }

    protected void setDOB (String newDOB)
    {
        dob = newDOB;
    }

    protected abstract void die();

    protected abstract void feed(int amount);

    protected abstract void sleep (int amount);

    protected abstract void play (int amount);

    protected abstract void annoy (int amount);

    protected abstract void cuddles (int amount);

    protected abstract void sick (int amount);
}
```

MyPet:

```
package IndividualPet; 

import GroupAnimal.Animal;


public class MyPet extends Animal
{

int Dec = 10;
int Inc = 10;


public MyPet(String aName, String aDOB,  int aRelease, int aLimbs, 
        double aWeight, double aHeight, int aEnergy, int aHungry) {
energy = aEnergy;
hungry = aHungry;
name = aName;
dob = aDOB;
toilet = aRelease;
limbs= aLimbs;
weight= aWeight;
height= aHeight;

}


    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub






enum Skill { ROOKIE, ADVANCED, EXPERT}
enum Concentration { LOW, MEDIUM, STRONG; }
enum Hygiene { POOR, GOOD, EXCELLENT; }



public void decHungry() {


    hungry -= Dec;

}

public void incEnergy() {

    energy += Inc;

}


@Override
protected void die() {
    Runtime.getRuntime().halt(0);{
    System.out.println("Your pet has died");
    }
}
@Override
protected void feed() {

     System.out.println("\nEating..."); 



       decHungry();
       incEnergy();

        if (hungry < 0 && energy > 100) {
            hungry = 0;
            energy = 100;
            System.out.println("I have ate enough!");
        }

        System.out.println("I've just ate dumplings, my current energy state is " + energy 
                +" and hungry state is " + hungry); 
        }



@Override
protected void sleep(int amount) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
protected void play(int amount) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
protected void annoy(int amount) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
protected void cuddles(int amount) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
protected void sick(int amount) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

So this method allows me to decrease hungry state and increase energy state although when it gets out of bounds it keeps printing 
**Eating...
I've just ate dumplings, my current energy state is 100 and hungry state is 0

Eating...
I have ate enough!
I've just ate dumplings, my current energy state is 100 and hungry state is 0

Eating...
I have ate enough!
I've just ate dumplings, my current energy state is 100 and hungry state is 0**

*How do I remove every print statement except "I have ate enough!" when it is out of bounds?*

```
@Override
protected void feed() {

     System.out.println("\nEating..."); 



       decHungry();
       incEnergy();

        if (hungry < 0 && energy > 100) {
            hungry = 0;
            energy = 100;
            System.out.println("I have ate enough!");
        }

        System.out.println("I've just ate dumplings, my current energy state is " + energy 
                +" and hungry state is " + hungry); 
        }
```

Anyone can throw any specific examples on how to do that?

Comment: Perhaps have a single loop for game ticks, and then operate logic on a single method that would determine what to do per-tick? Or even use `ScheduledFuture` for repeating tasks?

Comment: So you are asking us to write code for you ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have something that calls feed/sleep etc - the methods in MyPet?

Comment: method updated, its what i've got so far I'm not sure if this would work.

Comment: feed method updated, its what i've got so far I'm not sure if this would work.

Comment: I'd recommend a simple javax.swing.Timer to act s the main "game loop", this way when the timer ticks, it will be done within the context of the Event Dipatching Thread, where it is safe to update the UI, but which won't block it while in ts wait state

Answer (score 0):

While your question is too broad to give actual answers, here is some general advice:

You feeding your pet is part of the *business logic* of your program. It's what your program *does*.

You wanting to display some sort of animated progress to the user is part of the *user interface* of your program. It's how your program *presents* what it is doing to the user.

You will find that things come together a lot more smoothly if you put a conscious effort into keeping these two things separate. You will want to *present* the feeding to the user at a higher level, in your user interface code, not inside `MyPet` where your *logic* is.

For example, first define what your actual intentions are. If your intention is "give the animal X food once per second, Y times", then something like (pseudo code):

```
in ui:
   display progress dialog or progress bar
   create a 1 second timer and start it

in timer:
   animal.feed(X);
   if this is the Yth time it happened:
      stop timer
      close dialog / hide progress bar
   end if
```

The purpose of using a [timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) there rather than a direct loop is to allow Swing to continue processing events during delays (so your UI doesn't freeze), and also it makes it more straightforward to ensure that [component updates are done on the proper thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

If your intention is to give the animal N total food then just make a fancy animation for the user's benefit:

```
in ui:
   animal.feed(N)
   show and animate a progress bar, even though feeding logic has already run
```

Both lead to the same end result, both are valid, but the point is, keep your UI and logic separate, and make your code reflect your intentions. Note that neither of the above pseudocode examples involve putting anything UI related in `feed()`, and that any looping, if done, is purely a function of the UI and is also not done in `feed()`.

I hope that is helpful. I would give you more specific examples but there are simply too many possibilities. You'll have to attempt something first then come back here when you are running into a more specific issue.

Comment: player should be able to feed the animal (increasing the Hungry state), play with the animal (increasing the Happy state) and put the animal to sleep (increasing the Energy state) and if the animal is ignored then it will “die”. This could be represented in the console by using printing statements for now, later I will use Jframe and Jpanels for the UI and progress bars to actually show progress whether animal has been fed etc. timer will be used to measure time for which pet is left alone if exceeds certain amount it will die.

Comment: @user3482500 That is a good development strategy. The above still holds. By keeping those "delays" as a function of the UI, and keeping UI code (e.g. console input/output) out of your animal logic, you can define and test the behavior of the animal itself, with a temporary console UI, then swap in a Swing-based GUI later *without changing the code for `Animal`/`MyPet` at all* -- which is precisely the goal of this type of design.

Comment: @user3482500  You may also want to have a look at the [MVC Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm) for some design ideas.

Comment: yes, but I can't get my methods to work,  protected void feed(int amount) {
  
   System.out.println("\nEating..."); 
         for(int x=5; x!=0;x--){ 
             
             hungry+=10; 
             energy-=10; }
         
         System.out.println("I've just ate dumplings, my current energy state is " + energy 
           +" and hungry state is " + hungry);
  
  
 } this doesn't seem to affect the hungry state or energy state...

Comment: @user3482500 So you are saying, in that code, that the "I've just ate my dumplings" printout shows the same energy/hungry values that you had before the loop? Did you print energy/hungry both before and after the loop to verify that this was the case? What happened when you stepped through it in your debugger?

Comment: I've created a tester class in which:  `public static void main (String[] args) {
  
  
  //last two parameters are hungry and energy set to 50
  MyPet KungFuPanda = new MyPet("Charlie", "null", 5, 4, 100.0, 100.0, 50, 50);
  
  //executing feed method
  KungFuPanda.feed();
  
  //expected result energy 40 hungry, energy 60 
  
 }
}` **and they are unaffected energy is 0 hungry is 100**

Comment: @user3482500 That code doesn't match your original pasted code. You are calling `feed()` there with no parameters, but as far as I can tell, this is the first mention of such a method. The only `feed(...)` I see you have so far is one that takes an `int`. Please check to make sure your posted code is an accurate representation of what you are actually doing.

Comment: I have updated the MyPet code, it works now although, when it is past the limit of 100 and 0 it is printing now unwanted syso statements, how do I prevent this from happening?